# Kotlin extension function with request to rest server

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, kotlin-extension

I'm setting up extension function for Timber. I want to have kind of function to send log to my server.

The problem for me is Dagger. I have instance of RestService class in dagger and I'm using it in my whole app. 
But to use it I need inject somewhere this RestService. I can't do it in constructor because I haven't it.

I want to have something like this:

```
fun Timber.serverLogDebug(log: String) {
    restService.log(log)
}
```

Is it probably at all? It will be convenience for me to use my mechanism like simple Timber.d().
Alternatively I can call

```
restService.log(log)
```

in every place. But I have to have this instance everywhere.

Comment: You can take your `restService` object at **Application class** and use for your extensions from there statically.

Comment: u can send your restService also as an argument for `fun Timber.serverLogDebug(log: String,restService:RestService)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the file where you define the extension function, also define a "singleton" `object` to hold your `restService` instance, create a setter for it, and reference it from the logger function.

```
private object ServiceHolder {
    var restService: RestService
}

fun Timber.setRestService(restService: RestService) {
    ServiceHolder.restService = restService
}

fun Timber.serverLogDebug(log: String) {
    ServiceHolder.restService.log(log)
}
```

Now you can "statically inject" your service instance by calling `Timber.setRestService` where you plant your Timber `DebugTree`.

Note: If you want to log to the server every time you log (or every time you log an event of a specific level), you might be better off creating a custom `Timber.Tree`.